# How to set netty log level on selected spring boot Webclient instances

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

We have 2 different instances of spring boot Webclients. We want one of them to log all requests/responses and the other to log nothing. Settiing:

```
logging.level.reactor.netty.http.client=debug
```

in the application.properties file causes both instances to log requests/responses. Is there a way to programmatically set the log level on one of the instances to log debug levels and the other to not?

We create the first webclient like this:

WebClient.create();

For this one we don't want debug logging.
The second one, for which we want logging, we create like this:

```java
        return WebClient.builder()
                .clientConnector(createWebClientWithTimeout())
                // Add base url to all requests (callers only need to add the path and query params)
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                // Increase the buffer size from 256K to 1M
                .codecs(configurer -> configurer
                        .defaultCodecs()
                        .maxInMemorySize(1024 * 1024))
                // Filter to add bearer token to auth header before sending request
                .filter((request, next) -> getToken(custId).map(setAuthHeader(request)).flatMap(next::exchange))
                // Filter to send the request, and try again if it has an auth error
                .filter((request, next) -> next.exchange(request).flatMap(clientResponse -> {
                    :::
return Mono.just(clientResponse);
                })).build();
```

and

```java
    private ClientHttpConnector createWebClientWithTimeout() {
           // create reactor netty HTTP client
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newConnection()
                .wiretap("reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient",
                        LogLevel.DEBUG, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL)
                .compress(true)
                .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> {
                    tcpClient = tcpClient.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, linkedinConnectTimeoutInSeconds * 1000)
                            .doOnConnected(conn -> conn
                                    .addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(linkedinReadTimeoutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                                    .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(linkedinWriteTimeoutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)));
                    return tcpClient;
                });
        // create a client http connector using above http client
        return new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
    }
```

If we don't set logging.level.reactor.netty.http.client=debug, neither of these webclients log netty debug statements. If we set the debug parameter, both log the requests, the second one also logs request/response headers and bodies.

Comment: Do you enable `wiretap` for the http client?

Comment: We create the first webclient like this:

Comment: @VioletaGeorgieva I updated the description to include the code used to create the 2 webclients.

Comment: Can you try to enable only `logging.level.reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient=debug`

Comment: @VioletaGeorgieva That worked, thank you. I appreciate your help.